# Problem pointing domain Debian Apache sites enabled

Tags: debian, domain

well I'm trying to add an additional domain to my server.

in etc/apache2/sites-available/ I have the file like this

```
# This tell apache to enable this vhost for all ports
```

```
ServerName  example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example-com
    # Optional, allow override in .htaccess files
    <Directory /var/www/example-com>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/example-com/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/example-com/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # optional, log accesses and errors to a different file
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example-access.log combined
```

(I changed it to example.com from my domain)

and then I ran a2ensite, it said everything worked fine. I reloaded apache but still when I go to my domain it's just pointing to the regular default directory. Any ideas why it's not going to the directory I specified?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<VirtualHost *:80>` section in your config. Isn't it a mistype?
Place your configuration inside  section this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example-com
    # Optional, allow override in .htaccess files
    <Directory /var/www/example-com>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/example-com/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/example-com/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # optional, log accesses and errors to a different file
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then reload apache and see if the problem is fixed.